# Multiple employment histories with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to create a php form that allows you do add your employment history. I wanted it to work with javascript to add new fields such as in this link:  jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/, but with drop down lists to add a start date and end date, and then be able to POST this to php.

I am a newbie to javascript and am in need of help with this code if possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: copy and paste your code into the question as well as adding an actual question.

Comment: Sorry its my first time posting a question onto this. My question is how can i basically use javascript to add a second layer containing a text field and drop down lists (to enter start and end dates) for an employment history form. Sort of like the js fiddle link i have giving

Comment: @hsd Post your jsfiddle code in the question. When you try to link to jsfiddle SO says "include your code in the post as well"

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understanding that you want to add a date picker to your existing input?

If that's the case, and seeing how you're already using jQuery, you should check out [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) which has a [Datepicker module](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with great documentation.